# jstree 3.0.2: how to customize the jstree to have more than one field in the node

Tags: java, jquery, jstree, favorites

Iam trying to create a web application using java, spring and hibernate for managing favorite links. basically like the bookmark / favorites manager in IE
I have choosen jstree to implement it.

The requirement of my application are:
1. a tree can have groups and the groups can have subgroups
2. a group can have links
3. a group has one field i.e. name
4. a link has two fields i.e name and the url
5. moving of nodes inside the tree and CRUD operations

So far I am successful to implement all the functionality except for the link part. jstree by default will provide only one field to name the node, but in my case it require two fields one for name and other for url when the user tries to create a new link under a group and I need to have CRUD operations for the same.

Please help how it can be achieved using jstree. if in case I have choosen wrong plugin please guide me to use the right plugin which will help me achieve my functionality.